# Find an algorithm to find similar pizzas from a set of N pizzas

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I have this homework problem:

> You are given a stack of *n* pizza boxes of the same size, each containing 1 pizza. The pizzas in the boxes are sorted by increasing diameter; the diameters are all at most 40cm.
>
> 1a. Prove that there must exist two pizzas in the stack
> whose diameters differ by at most 40/(*n*−1) cm.
> 1b. Give an algorithm for ﬁnding such a pair. The only way your algorithm may learn the diameter of a pizza is by opening its box and measuring it. We'll call that operation *measure*(*i*), where *i* is the number of the box being opened. Your algorithm should open as few pizza boxes as possible. For full credit, it should open *O*(log *n*) boxes in the worst case.

For 1a, I don't know how to prove that mathematically. For 1b, I understand that I will have to use binary search, but I don't know exactly how to implement that.

How do I go about this problem? I'd appreciate any hints, or any suggestions how to approach it.

Comment: Have you read the lecture notes? (Or attended them)

Comment: Yes, I have attended the lectures. Such a question was not discussed. Professor has discussed time complexity and sorting algorithm but has not taught us how to tackle these kinds of problem.

Comment: When I went to University I attended lectures. I then spent 2/3 hours reading around the topics. Does this differ now - you are unable to access the library (I did not have the luxury of the internet).

Comment: Sir, I have read the required reading material. I am not trying to bullshit my way through college. I am simply asking for help as I am confused on how should I solve the problem. I don't think a reading material will help solve a puzzle type question. I have the knowledge I am unable to apply it, and so I am crying for help.

Comment: The required reading is the minimum. Read around the subject and get a 1st.

Comment: "get a 1st" you mean part 1 will help me solve part 2? I think part 1 is wrong. I have commented that in the answer given to me below. Please advice any book that you think I should read so I know how to tackle these questions

Comment: To add to Ed's comments a bit: I know it's painful, but sometimes the struggle is what's important. Part of this class is learning "how to think"; we can't teach you that, but if you struggle with it a bit, I'm confident you'll manage it on your own. (That said, your first comment to Ivaylo Stoev's answer below is a much better question. It shows a specific place where your thinking has gone wrong, and that's exactly the sort of thing we can help with.)

Comment: Hint for 1b: Look at the box in the middle of the stack. Its diameter can be greater than 40/2 = 20 cm or not. Decide whether to look above it or below it.

Answer (score 1):

For 1a you could use induction:

Basically: 
Assume n=2 (at least two pizzas, otherwise no difference) and maximize difference. 
Let one of the pizzas have a diameter of 40 and the other one x
Then we have 40-x < 40/(2-1) which is true.

Induction step n=>n+1
and you can try from there...

Comment: I agree with what you are saying. But consider another case. Suppose n=5, and I  have pizzas of diameter 1, 2 ,3,5,40. So from what I understand the difference can be atmost 10 in this case. But clearly the difference between 1 and 40 is 39. So how does the formula hold. Thank you for your reply

Comment: You are not looking for the maximum difference. you are looking for at least two that satisfy the condition.

Comment: There is no need for induction. Assume that there is no pair of successive pizzas such that the difference in diameter is greater than 40/(n−1); it follows that the diameter of the largest pizza is greater than the diameter of the smallest pizza + (n−1)  * 40/(n−1) = 40. But the diameter of the largest pizza is known to be not greater than 40cm.